# ¿Cómo guardar información de un editor de texto de summenote desde asp.net C# y mostrarlo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Necesito una idea de como guardar información de un editor de texto de summenote desde asp.net C# y mostrarlo usando sql server.

El editor de texto contendrá imágenes y texto, las cuales tengo que mostrarlo ordenado en otra pagina web.

adjunto imagen
Saludos,

Comment: que componente editor estas utilizando ? es uno integrado con asp.net o es basado en jquery

Answer (score 1):

El editor de texto seguramente se base en html con algun componente como ser

http://ckeditor.com/

[jHtmlArea - WYSIWYG HTML Editor for jQuery](https://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/)

Desde codigo `javascript` podrias tomar el contenido y enviarlo al servidor en una llamada `ajax` con `jquery`

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

De esta forma usando `$.ajax` puedes invocar un `[WebMthod]` y pasarle el html del editor para persistirlo en sql server.
Para mostrar el contenido seria el proceso contrario usarias `$.ajax` para obtener el html que asignarias al editor, pero usando siempre codigo cliente.

Esto lo realizas asi porque el editor funciona desde el cliente y no se integra con asp.net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462787/is-it-possible-to-get-value-from-summernote-editor-in-asp-net-web-forms, aquí una solución pero en StackOverflow en inglés